# Priority in task manager - HDD write priority too or only CPU priority?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

In Windows (8.1) I can set the Priority of a Program in the Task Manager (Details).

Does this affect CPU Priority only or HDD (write) priority too?

E.G.: HDD is at 100% load due to VMWare. A program with normal priority needs to write but gets delayed. Does the program get higher write priority for the HDD if the priority in the task manager is set to High or Realtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taskmanager only adjust the CPU priority. To set the IO Priority you can use the program [ProcessHacker](https://wj32.org/processhacker/)

[image]

Lower the IO priority of VMware to Low so that programs with normal IO priority are not effected too much.